# Angular2 Redirect route doesn't change browser url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Trying to create my redirect route in my angular2 app.

But my problem is that when someone enter an invalid path like  'nopath' then user is redirected to the 'HomeComponent' but the url still keep the  '/#/nopath'

I want the redirectTo route to change the url too! How should I achieve this?

Should I put an if in my HomeComponent constructor that check the current url and change his route to homecomponent? Or there is something I am missing?

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'users', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true});
```

EDIT:

Tried this, but i doesn't get the redirect to the home component

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full' , redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'users', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: maybe don't use a redirect route, just use "**", component: HomeComponent (instead of redirect). (NM tried it a couple of ways, yeah I wouldn't do this).

Comment: Are you using the latest Angular2 and Router version? I saw a similar issue mentioned recently where updating solved it.

Comment: i use 3.2.3 version of the router, i dont know how to check if i have the latest version

Comment: Check the `CHANGELOG.md` in the GitHub repo

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the version in the CHANGELOG.md of the router: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/CHANGELOG.md  it say 3.0.0 - RC2  but i use 3.2.3 version so something doesn't in the version!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, i didn't find any better way than hacking the Angular2 Router.

Here is my solution, it's not a beautifull way to fix the problem... but at least it work as i want!

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'users', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [RedirectToHomeGuard] }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

RedirectToHomeGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectToHomeGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

You guys think it could be a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

For me, this problem was caused by importing the module containing the home component in AppModule.

Comment: You know it's 2 year old ? It was a bug inside their code because it's not a problem anymore... And in that time i was using a single module for the application so your expectation is wrong.

Comment: @Vince other people are referencing these answers too

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo:'home'},  
   //<<<-----added redirectTo attribute

  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent  },                
   //<<<----added this line


  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'users', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }   //<<<--- updated line
];
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it keep the nopath in the url and i doesn't get redirected to HomeComponent

Comment: I tried the redirectTo: 'home' too and it keep the bad url in the browser, i need to enter push enter a second time so it change the url bu reloading the app completly...

Comment: ** i need to push enter a second time in the browser url to make the app reload and that work.. but it's a strange behaviour i want that my user that write a bad url be redirected to my home component with the home url without the need to reload the app

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is because you use HashlocationStrategy. If you don't reaaaally need it, I would remove it, then it should work and url should change. It does not seem to (yet) be any workaround this, unless you come up with one :)

Comment: I don't think it is because of HashLocationStrategy.

Comment: i need the HashLocationStrategy for my NodeJS server to know that it's a angular path

Comment: @micronyks okay, then it was just for me, when I just now tested it out of curiousity and the problem appeared for me as well. And Vince, I suspected you need it, why else would you have used it. Sorry, can't help you. Maybe I'll play around with my code and see if I come up with something. I doubt it though :D

Comment: Should i Post it as a bug in the router of angular2 ?

Comment: Even though micronlyks says it shouldn't matter, and I respect that, cuz I assume he's much more experienced than me. But in my opinion this is suspicious that when I added `useHash: true` on my app the problem appeared for me as well, in an app where that problem is not present when it is removed. So I think there is something to it, and if so, it should be reported, cuz that is a really annoying thing!

Comment: @Vince I'm sure its not a bug. We all have been using `**` path.

Comment: @Vince problem is with `redirectTo:''` because of `patchMatch:full` some problem is happening. You can redirect it using component directly. Updating answer.

Comment: using the component property is worse than the redirectTo, because even if i reload the path multiple time i keep the bad url but it show the homecomponent

Comment: and the routerLinkActive think i'm in the 'nopath' link so my navbar is not activating the home menu

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is too late but I think the problem should be with the base href tag. I used something like the code below in my index.html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyCoolApp</title>
  <base href=".">
</head>
```

Basically using href="." broke the routing. Instead if you use href="/" that will do the trick.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyCoolApp</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

So now the routing works and all the non-matching routes will end up on "**" path and since "/" is used as base url to find the *-bundle.js files they will be found. I think that is why when you navigate to "/" everything works again.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the original question/problem.

Comment: The cause of the problem could be that the routing uses the relative path instead of absolute one and ' ' relatively to nopath would be nopath. At least it was in my case.