# How to handle incorrect routes in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular. I had to handle all the invalid routes. In my app.module the following is defined

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'login'
}
```

Which means for all kinds of different routes (not specified) it will go to login screen(component)

So in my application I did following:

1. Hit my angular website. which shows login screen.
2. Entered credentials and logged in successfully.
3. Now changed the url in address bar to some route like `www.mysite.com\blahblah`. Then entered
4. It takes me to login page which is correct
5. Now when I login again putting correct credentials. It stays on login page.

How can I handle this?

I guess since the return url is `www.mysite.com\blahblah` which is invalid, post successful login it goes there and comes back to login because of the route

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'login'
}
```

Which is like a recursive thing. Please suggest.

Comment: do you want the browser url to change to your default redirect? 
If yes you can use the answer suggested in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409578/angular2-redirect-route-doesnt-change-browser-url

Comment: you can check the stored sign in credentials (depending on how you handle auth) and check in the Init of the login if user is signed in and forward him to the right page

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?